# Emacs: starting a new inferior python shell when evaluating buffer

Tags: python, emacs

I am working in vanilla Emacs 23 on various python programs, when I evaluate a buffer, an inferior python shell is started as expected and the scripts run fine...

This is all fine, however, when working on multiple (unrelated) projects, the same python instance is used, is there a way I can create a new inferior python shell per source file?

Thanks

Comment: What mode do you use?

Comment: I'm using the default python.el...

Answer (score 2):

When I need a new inferior python shell in emacs and want to specify which python buffers send code to each shell I do the following.  This gives me a little more control.

1. Use the M-x rename-buffer command to set the existing inferior shell buffer name to something like *Python-otherbuff*
2. (setq-local python-shell-buffer-name "Python-otherbuff") in each buffer which should interact with the old inferior shell.
3. Use the usual command to create a new inferior python shell (e.g. C-c C-p) which will create a buffer called *Python* which all python buffers will interact with by default.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully tested this, but I think this will work:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local python-shell-buffer-name 
                        (format "Python %s" (buffer-file-name)))))
```

This should cause every buffer to use a different buffer name when launching a python shell.  Each python shell buffer with a different name should have its own inferior python process.

Comment: I just had a try with this (evaluated in *scratch*) and does not seem to have the desired effect. Would welcome an independent test to see if its just me, lisp is really not my thing... Thanks...

Comment: I tested this briefly and it seems to work for me, though I'm on Emacs 26, so there could be a difference there.  Make sure when testing that you do something to cause the hook to run; e.g. if you have open Python buffers you can toggle `python-mode` off and on, or close and re-open the file, or just restart emacs.

Comment: I tried this at home (on a later version of emacs and it works with no issues, however, on Emacs 23.1.1 it doesn't seem to have the same effect and the same running instance is used when hitting C-c C-c...